# Is it possible to determine how many unique users there are for a custom GPT?

Tags: gpt, openai

I’ve created a couple dozen custom OpenAI GPTs. Most are barely used; but a few have good usage numbers. My most used is called [Data Science Consultant](https://chat.openai.com/g/g-u9rFlUhxK-data-science-consultant).

Is it possible to know how many people are using a specific custom GPT? I would like to know if I have a handful of die hard users, or many occasional users.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One potential way (although not advisable/scalable unless they can be created via API on the fly) would be to create a unique GPT each time with the same label/settings/configuration etc... and set its sharing URL to "private with link" behind a registration wall, where new users (whether free or paying) each get their distinct link after signup (hopefully no one has to do that at scale as I imagine OpenAI will eventually add such metrics to their upcoming GPT store, which would be a welcomed add!). Hope that helps.